# Smallest singular value of the sum of i.i.d. random rectangular matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Suppose $E_i$'s are iid random matrices (not square) such that 
$\mathbb{E}[E_i] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[E_i^TE_j] = 0$ for $i\ne j$.

Let $M = \sum_{i=1}^n E_i$.
It is clear that 
$$
H^* = \mathbb{E}[M^TM] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[E_i^TE_i]. 
$$
Suppose further that $0 < \lambda_{\min}(H^*) \le \lambda_{\max}(H^*) < \infty$.

I would like to have a "Matrix Chernoff" like inequality:
$$
P\left[ \lambda_{\min}(M^TM) > (1-\epsilon)\lambda_{\min}(H^*) \right] > 1 - g(\epsilon).
$$

However, the standard Matrix Chernoff cannot apply because $M^TM$ is not a sum of independent Hermitian matrices.

Note that
$$
M^TM = G + Y, \qquad Y = \sum_{i \ne j} E_i^TE_j,
\qquad
G = \sum_{i=1}^n E_i^TE_i.
$$
But I feel that this can as the contribution of $Y$ to $M^TM$ would be small.
However, since $Y$ is no longer positive definite (although symmetric), I am not sure how to proceed.

Any helps/comments/answers will be very appreciated.